# Access violation writing location for initializing a variable?

Tags: c, pointers, memory

I'm working on some old C code and I have this error occurring at runtime for reasons I cannot understand.

```
Unhandled exception at 0x00A11A7C in Program.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000034.
```

It is this line that the debugger stops at that throws this error:

```
Node *car = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
```

What's odd is that the program was running just fine prior. This function is called many times and just prints out car facts for each one. Suddenly on a random car this line just crashes the execution.

This is the first line of the function. How is it possible for this to be happening?

Comment: Although the error may be detected at that line, it's probably caused by accessing a previously malloced piece of memory incorrectly, messing up malloc's bookkeeping information.

Comment: @ooga: Could you elaborate? The variable is declared right there. Are you talking about another variable being malloc'd somehow messing that up? How could that be?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm saying. Unfortunately, I can't go into the details of how malloc works. Look at how you're handling previously allocated objects. There is a bug lurking there somewhere.

Comment: @ooga: So there is a bug somewhere in my program? Oh boy. Now to scan thousands of lines.

Comment: Check array indices in particular.

Comment: I would normally recommend using valgrind to locate the problem, but I guess you are using windows. You might want to try using a tool like https://code.google.com/p/drmemory/

Comment: Or perhaps `dmalloc`.